# cmd после вызова Winrar каталог еще 5 секунд заблокирован

Tags: cmd, winrar

Вызываю в cmd winrar. Разархивирую архив в каталог. Потом еще несколько секунд не могу переименовать этот каталог, "отказано в доступе".

"c:\Program Files\winrar\rar.exe" x "c:\inst\temp\prog.rar" "C:\inst\temp"

ren "C:\inst\temp" update

выдает "отказано в доступе"
повторяю команду ren в cmd несколько раз вручную, и она выполняется спустя 5 секунд примерно. А если в скрипте это делать, то эта команда там она сразу выполняется 
без получения доступа.
Как переименовать каталог сразу после извлечения архива?

Comment: Конструкцию `&&` пробовал?

Comment: нет не пробовал. Не нашел поиском что это означает. Можно подробнее.? Я думаю winrar создает какие-то временные файлы, при разархивировании. Если архив большой, то этих файлов много. Потом удаляет эти файлы. Или что то подобное.

Comment: "Если прошлая команда выполнилась ок, то дёргаем следующую." https://blog.pridybailo.com/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-bash/ в cmd && тоже пашет.